# How do I get Account Information Through Algorand TypeScript SDK?

Tags: smartcontracts, algorand

So Basically I'm trying to get Account Information.

Method: **Algodv2accountInformation**,

returns the **AccountInformation type**, but after calling .do()

.i.e

```
Algodv2accountInformation.do()
```

the return type is a more generic

```
<Promise<Record<string, any>>
```

What is the right way to make this api call but have it return right Information.

**`<AccountInformation>`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just checked their docs,
It is confusing as docs says it returns

**`<AccountInformation>`**

[image: Algorand Account Information TypeScript]

[Here's Link to docs](https://algorand.github.io/js-algorand-sdk/classes/Algodv2.html#accountInformation)

<**AccountInformation**> is encapsulating request, not response.

What you can do it leverage  class,
as it extends Base Class which does takes in **Record<string,any>** as input.

So the JSON you get from running .do() on .

```
accountInformation(account.addr).do():
{
  address: 'LFNDB6ADWN7M3HFA7TSBKW4ZV7Q3TAJ2TWAGHH35WFGQAVGTJGFVJXQASI',
  amount: 10000000,
  'amount-without-pending-rewards': 10000000,
  'apps-local-state': [],
  'apps-total-schema': { 'num-byte-slice': 0, 'num-uint': 0 },
  assets: [],
  'created-apps': [],
  'created-assets': [],
  'min-balance': 100000,
  'pending-rewards': 0,
  'reward-base': 0,
  rewards: 0,
  round: 32,
  status: 'Offline',
  'total-apps-opted-in': 0,
  'total-assets-opted-in': 0,
  'total-created-apps': 0,
  'total-created-assets': 0
}
```

Could be **passed to** Account(Record<String, any>) as follows:

```
new algosdk.modelsv2.Account(info):
Account {
  address: 'LFNDB6ADWN7M3HFA7TSBKW4ZV7Q3TAJ2TWAGHH35WFGQAVGTJGFVJXQASI',
  amount: 10000000,
  amountWithoutPendingRewards: undefined,
  minBalance: undefined,
  pendingRewards: undefined,
  rewards: 0,
  round: 32,
  status: 'Offline',
  totalAppsOptedIn: undefined,
  totalAssetsOptedIn: undefined,
  totalCreatedApps: undefined,
  totalCreatedAssets: undefined,
  appsLocalState: undefined,
  appsTotalExtraPages: undefined,
  appsTotalSchema: undefined,
  assets: [],
  authAddr: undefined,
  createdApps: undefined,
  createdAssets: undefined,
  participation: undefined,
  rewardBase: undefined,
  sigType: undefined,
  attribute_map: {
    address: 'address',
    amount: 'amount',
    amountWithoutPendingRewards: 'amount-without-pending-rewards',
    minBalance: 'min-balance',
    pendingRewards: 'pending-rewards',
    rewards: 'rewards',
    round: 'round',
    status: 'status',
    totalAppsOptedIn: 'total-apps-opted-in',
    totalAssetsOptedIn: 'total-assets-opted-in',
    totalCreatedApps: 'total-created-apps',
    totalCreatedAssets: 'total-created-assets',
    appsLocalState: 'apps-local-state',
    appsTotalExtraPages: 'apps-total-extra-pages',
    appsTotalSchema: 'apps-total-schema',
    assets: 'assets',
    authAddr: 'auth-addr',
    createdApps: 'created-apps',
    createdAssets: 'created-assets',
    participation: 'participation',
    rewardBase: 'reward-base',
    sigType: 'sig-type'
  }
}
```

And! Voilla! you've got your account model object!

Actually there should be some method .getModel(),
I'll create a PR, as this should be part of SDK.

Comment: If i do that I get this error "Argument of type 'Record<string, any>' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ address: string; amount: number | ... "